# Using structs of derived class y base template

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I have a base template:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
        void method(T);
};
```

And a derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base<Derived::status_t>
{
    public:
     typedef struct
     {
        uint8_t value;
     } status_t; 
}
```

I'm have more derived classes, each one with it status_t specific struct. I want to use these structs in the base class, but the compiler give me an error:

Error[Pe070]: incomplete type is not allowed.

I suppose that the problem is that the struct is not defined in the moment that the base constructor is called. Is there any way to maintain the struct in the derived class and use it un the base template?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think you can use any type from the class definition at all as template argument there (the compiler doesn't know the types yet at this point). It isn't related to the base constructor. Do you _need_ it that way? Simply declare the `status_t` types outside the class and if necessary import with something like `using status_t = `. Also in C++ you should not typedef the `struct`. Just declare it as `struct status_t {...};`.

Comment: you can pull the definition of the `status_t` up to another base class such that your derived would be `struct Derived : Derived_base, Base<Derived_base::status_t> {};`. However, without more context it is not clear why `status_t` needs to be defined inside `Derived`. What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is a much simpler solution

Comment: maybe a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would like to maintain the status_t struct in the derived class because I have a lot of deriveclassX, each one with a different parameters in status_t.

Comment: your base class could use `T::status_t` if that works for your scenario

Comment: @dan, it would be possible y the base clase includes all the derived classes. But I don't think that this would be a good practice.

Comment: @user1799803 the implementations will include the base class, so it should be fine