# Can I fill a template parameter with a nested class in this class?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, I got a class looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
 public:
  T* t;
   ...
};
```

then (how) can I extends the class which is similar like this?

```
class TestImplement : Test<TestImplement::TestInner> // the TestInner class is defind in the class {
  class TestInner {};
  ...
};
```

Since the `TestInner` is defined after where the template needs, this code is illegal, and a forward declaration is useless too.

Comment: Strange that two very similar questions appear in such a short span of time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722206/using-structs-of-derived-class-y-base-template

Comment: @StoryTeller https://www.quora.com/What-causes-the-synchronicity-in-the-universe-when-were-reading-a-book-and-then-hear-the-same-word-we-just-read-on-the-radio-or-tv-at-the-same-time-and-how-do-we-think-of-a-song-and-then-turn-on-the-radio-and-the-song-is-playing

Comment: @StoryTeller Maybe it's just a coincidence...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit NSFW tree inside, heh.

Comment: @jrok: Hah, nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you simply can't do that, and you've already pointed out why that is.

Thinking more about logic than about syntax, since the base class definition may very well differ depending on what its template argument is, and since the base class definition may very well affect the way `TestInner` works, you are attempting to create a circular dependency which is just not possible in our physical reality.

You could experiment with using `TestImplement` as the template argument (CRTP!) and then look up `typename TemplateArgument::TestInner` from within the base, but even if this works I doubt its clarity.

I'd use a non-nested class instead.

Comment: "the base class definition may very well differ depending on what its template argument is" - this is the exact reason to use CRTP, or static polymorphism.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak Hence my suggestion to use CRTP 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you are right, I'm transporting some code from Java to C++, Unlike in Java, inner class objects don't have an implicit reference to an outer object, so stick the Java nested class layout(syntax) is useless, I'll move the inner class out.